# Create a groove button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, uibutton, flutter-layout

Is it posible to make a button like the image? It doesn't need to be circular just is there anyway to gice that groove effect to a raised button and text field areas in Flutter?
Also link of the image is "https://css-tricks.com/circular-3d-buttons/"
This is made by css, if there is any trick to do it with material design maybe css import for such a work?

[image: Groove button with css]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a pretty similar result by using a RawMaterialButton and a decorated Container.

[image]

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),      
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
     shape: BoxShape.circle,
     gradient: LinearGradient(
       begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
       end: Alignment.topCenter,
       stops: [0.0 , 0.5, 1.0],
       colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white, Colors.grey[200]]
     )  
  ),
  child: RawMaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: new Icon(
      Icons.settings,
        color: Colors.grey[600],
        size: 28.0,
     ),
     shape: new CircleBorder(),
     elevation: 2.0,
     fillColor: Colors.white,
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
   )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this

```
    new RawMaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: new Icon(
     Icons.pause,
     color: Colors.blue,
     size: 35.0,
  ),
  shape: new CircleBorder(),
  elevation: 2.0,
  fillColor: Colors.white,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
),
```